# What's wrong? I am receiving error msg: Invalid arguments passed in eval()

Tags: php, join, eval

I write down my php code:

```
<?php
        // 已有指定 material, 顯示 material 資訊
        if (strlen($m_id) > 0) {
            // 此 material 屬於哪些 mgroup
            $group_info = $mUtil->groupInfo($m_id);
            $group_names = array();
            foreach ($group_info as $mg_id => $row) {
                if (!$row["not_in_group"]) {
                    $group_names[] = $row["mg_name"];
                }
            }
        }
    ?>

  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2"><?php echo $m_name; ?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th>Formula</th>
      <td width="80%"><?php echo $formula; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th>Alias</th>
      <td><?php echo $alias; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th>In groups</th>
      <!-- join() == implode() -->
      <td><?php echo join($group_names, ",&nbsp; "); ?></td>
    </tr>
  </table><br /><br />
```

but I get these error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: group_names in eval() (line 97 of D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in eval() (line 97 of D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Undefined variable: group_names in eval() (line 97 of D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in eval() (line 97 of D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 2):

The undefined errors are due to variables like `$group_names` only being defined once

```
if (strlen($m_id) > 0) { ... } //condition is true.
```

Make sure the variable you are using are instantiated before using them.

Using `isset($instancename)` can be one of the ways to deal with this.

Example:

```
if(!isset($group_names)) $group_names = array();
// ^ if $group_names is not found then at least initialize it as an empty array
//   so that the rest of the script can go easy
```

---

Also, `join()` needs a glue to join the array, which is not in correct order.

```
<?php echo join(", ", $group_names); ?>
```

---

<sub>NOTE: The use of `eval()`, however, has to be discouraged</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments to the join function are not correct, read about it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php

Comment: After closer inspection, they can be in either order, Jon has the correct answer, your $group_names is not an array because strlen($m_id) <= 0

Answer (score 1):

If the condition `strlen($m_id) > 0` is `false` then `$group_names` will not be initialized. However, later you are using it unconditionally:

```
<td><?php echo join($group_names, ",&nbsp; "); ?></td>
```

Solution: move the initialization `$group_names = array()` outside the condition.

Apart from that, you have the wrong order the arguments of `join` (you should switch them).